# Cannot Adjust Brightness using Gallium Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, graphics, brightness, backlight, gallium

I recently updated my linux kernal from 3.1.9 to 4.2.0.  Since the update I can no longer adjust the brightness.  Here the details of my computer

Computer:Dell-Inspiron
Processor:Intel
Graphics: Galliuum 0.4 on llvmpip (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)

When I run `ls /sys/class/backlight`
It returns nothing.

I have also edited the grub file but it seems to not have worked.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in same situation, and I have tried a lot of things, even edited grub file with different attempts, but not have worked too. I found a way here in AskUbuntu. I don't know if you already resolved that, so:

My kernel: 4.10
Computer: Avell Titanium
Processor: intel i7
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)

The only thing that really works for me was change to the NVidia proprietary drivers in: *System Settings* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers*.

> Thanks to dobey in https://askubuntu.com/a/787057/682972